# How to use array when declaring sub VB

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering is there was a way to use an array when declaring a sub.

Example:

```
Public Class Form1
Private PictureBox(2) as PictureBox

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
PictureBox(0) = PictureBox1
PictureBox(1) = PictureBox2
PictureBox(2) = PictureBox3

Private Sub PictureBox_mouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox(1).MouseDown
'do stuff here
end sub
```

Comment: `Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown, Handles PictureBox2.MouseDown, Handles PictureBox2.MouseDown`  the array is just a collection, you want the attach to the controls *inside it*

Comment: @Plutonix That won't work, for what I want to do more picture boxes are created and I need to have them in the sub aswell

Comment: You cant hook up handlers for controls which dont exist.  you will have to use AddHandler when you create them

Answer (score 0):

This is the method Plutonix suggested in the comments applied to your code. Note that no array is needed.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf (ctrl) Is PictureBox Then
                AddHandler DirectCast(ctrl, PictureBox).MouseDown, AddressOf PictureBox_MouseDown
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub PictureBox_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        'Code here will apply to every PictureBox in your form
    End Sub
End Class
```

Also note that instead of `DirectCast(ctrl, PictureBox).MouseDown`, you could just use `ctrl.MouseDown`. Using `DirectCast` simply helps you avoid making mistakes by cluing IntelliSense and the compiler in on what you're doing.